# jQuery Select2 Blocked By CORS Policy in Laravel Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cors, jquery-select2

I am trying to use jQuery Select2 in Laravel Vue. But I have an error below when I use my base url. But, when I use another API service like `https://countriesnow.space/api/v0.1/countries/population/cities`, it's okey, data can be retrieved. What's wrong? I've been trying to solve this problem but nothing is gonna work.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/my-project/laravue/api/staff/categories/search-sub-categories/?_type=query' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('categories/search-sub-categories/{id}', [CategoryController::class, 'searchSubCategories']);
```

**Controller**

```
public function searchSubCategories(Request $request, $id)
{
    $keyword = $request->get('q');

    $subCategories = SubCategory::with('category')
        ->orWhereDoesntHave('category')
        ->OrWhereHas('category', function ($q) use ($id) {
            $q->where('id', $id);
        })
        ->where("subcategory_name", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")
        ->get();

    return response()->json([
        'sub_categories' => $subCategories,
    ]);
}
```

**View**

```
<div v-show="isFormAssignCategoryMode" class="form-group">
                  <select
                    selected="selected"
                    multiple
                    class="form-control sub_categories"
                    name="sub_categories[]"
                    id="sub_categories"
                  ></select>
                </div>

$('#sub_categories').select2({
 ajax: {
    url: `${BASE_URL}/api/staff/categories/search-sub-categories/` + self.form.id,
    crossDomain: true,
    cors: true,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, Content-Type, Authorization, X-Auth-Token',
    },
   processResults: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      return {
        results: data.map(function (item) {
          return {
            id: item.id,
            text: item.name,
          };
        }),
      };
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing here is that the port is missing in your Base_URL `:8080`, that is causing this CORS error.

To solve you need to add proxy to your VUE app, check this will help you https://dev.to/alirezahamid/how-to-fix-cors-issue-in-vuejs-545o

Or if you're using Nuxtjs then check this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/proxy

Also, I recommend you to use [vue-select2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-select2), to avoid using Jquery code inside your Vue components

Comment: I use Vue CLI 3 and it actually run in `http://localhost:8080`. But, the API is running in `http://localhost/my-project/laravue/`. I always use this way in any API request and it's fine. Only this case I have a problem with CORS. I have no idea.

Comment: The browser will not let any http request from different origins.
did you try this in `vue.config.js` ?
`module.exports = {
 devServer: {
     proxy: 'https://localhost'
 } }
`

Comment: Note that you must change the base url in your ajax call to be `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: I've tried to change the url to `http://localhost:8080` by running `php artisan serve`. And yes, this is work. CORS is gone now. But I got a new problem. I am unable to get data, it show me `http://localhost:8000/api/staff/categories/search-sub-categories/?_type=query 404 (Not Found)`. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I assume that you still didn't setup the proxy properly in the vue.config.js
Because now, you still requesting from VUE cli server.
I think you must define all the routes with `/api/` to take you to Laravel api by following this example from their official documentation
`proxy: {
    '^/api': {
      target: 'http://localhost'
    }
  }`
https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy